# How to check exist ou in active directory with vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I try to integrate Human Resource DB to Active Directory.
Once I use sql ,getting all person and department  and then write to ad.
but if a department built new how to check is exist or new in active directory,also person also computer.

Answer (score 1):

This article should be helpful:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/LDAP_Using_VBnet.aspx

My thought is that you would create a List of People (OUs) , and once you have such a List, it is very simple to create a function to check the List to see if a specific person exists.

Therefore, If the person does not exist -- CreatePerson()

Otherwise, If the person exists -- UpdatePerson()

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.   You might also want to look at the Account Management [sample application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384374.aspx) for idea.  To check for an OU you can use [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) to instantiate a DirectoryEntry based on the OU's path (or a searcher to find it).  If it doesn't exist, you need get the DirectoryEntry object for the parent OU and then create a new OrganizationUnit using Invoke to invoke the ADSI create method.

Answer (score 0):

thanks JaredPar for answer.
give me sample code in vb.net.
I could not find sample code.

while create ou with above code
Try

```
                objOU = objADAM.Children.Add(strOU, "OrganizationalUnit")
                objOU.Properties("description").Add(dr.GetValue(2).ToString)
                objOU.CommitChanges()

            Catch de As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("Error:   Create failed.")
                Console.WriteLine("         {0}", de.Message)
                Return
            End Try
```